# Adding a method to Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an `any` method to `Array`.

```js
Array.prototype.any = (pred) => {
  for(const item of this) {
    if (pred(item)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log([1, 2, 3].any(num => num === 3))
```

...but I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.any (array.js:4)
    at array.js:13
```

I was expecting `true` to be printed to to the console. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `TypeError: this is not iterable` is the error you’re actually getting.

Comment: It looks like because I'm using `this`, I needed to use traditional `function` syntax rather than arrow function (`() => {}`) syntax.

Comment: @SebastianSimon actually no, after replacing the arrow function with a regular function I don't get any error. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a comment to that effect @charlietfl

Comment: do you know [Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: @MichaelDorst _“after replacing the arrow function with a regular function I don't get any error”_ — Exactly. Read the linked question again. It’s all explained there.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes, obviously, but the error I _actually got_ was the one that I posted, so why did you tell me I was "actually getting" a different error?

Comment: @MichaelDorst There’s no way to reproduce the error you originally posted. The only other reproducible error was the one related to `this`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon copy that code into a file named `array.js` and call `node array.js` and you will see the error I posted.

Comment: @MichaelDorst Wow! That’s Chrome/V8’s way of telling you that `window` is not iterable. It actually _is_ the same error, but the V8 error message is near useless. The error is reproducible with `for(const x of window);` (or `this` instead of `window` outside strict mode). You’ll find that `window` is not iterable (sensible error message in Firefox). What JS is trying to do is call the [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) method on `window`. The method resolves to `undefined`, hence Node says it’s not a function.